# Creating a numerical table of values from an interpolating function resulting from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, image-processing, interpolation, physics

I am trying to carry out point "Implementing Map" on this paper [Interstellar wormholes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03809.pdf) however I am using my own equations not those given (only the same method).

### Part 1

I am trying to create a numerical table (list) of values of my range of angles $\phi cs$ and the resulting numerical output of my numerical differential equations which are dependent on these angles

I have done this so far

```
Quit

numericalmap = {};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, 
  ϕcsgen = (1 + 0.1 i)*Pi;
  Nx = Sin[θcs]*Cos[ϕcsgen];
  Ny = Sin[θcs]*Sin[ϕcsgen];
  Nz = Cos[θcs];
  nr = -Nx;
  nϕ = -Ny;
  nθ = Nz;
  b = rc*Sin[θc]*nϕ/(1 - 2 M/rc)^1/2;
  B2 = rc^2/(1 - 2 M/rc)*(nϕ^2 + nθ^2);
  prinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1))*nr;
  pθinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1/2))*rc*nθ;
  M = 1; E0 = 1; θcs = Pi/2;
  {rc, θc, ϕc} = {200, Pi/2, 0};
  ham = 
    {t'[λ] + E0/(1 - (2 M)/r[λ]) == 0, 
     r'[λ] - (1 - (2 M)/r[λ]) pr[λ] == 0, 
     θ'[λ] - Pθ[λ]/r[λ]^2 == 0, 
     ϕ'[λ] - b/(r[λ]*Sin[θ[λ]])^2 == 0, 
     pr'[λ] + M/r[λ]^2 (E0^2/(1 - (2 M)/r[λ])^2 + 
     pr[λ]^2) - B2/r[λ]^3 == 0, 
     Pθ'[λ] - (b^2*Cos[θ[λ]])/(r[λ]^2*Sin[θ[λ]]^3) == 0};
  haminital = 
    {t[0] == 0, r[0] == rc, θ[0] == θc, ϕ[0] == ϕc, 
     pr[0] == prinitial, Pθ[0] == pθinitial};
  sol = NDSolveValue[{ham, haminital}, {t, r, θ, ϕ, pr, Pθ}, {λ, -100, 0}][[4]]; 
  ϕ2[λ_] = ϕ[λ] /. sol; (* ##### *)
  numericalmap = Append[numericalmap, {ϕcsgen, ϕ2[-100]}]]
```

This leads to some errors occurring but not entirely sure how to fix it.

I would like to have the numerical value of $\phi[-100] $ evaluated in each iteration not have some interpolating function. Note this is the function that results from the numerical integration evaluated at the end of the integration limit

Does anyone know how to get the numerical value of our function for $\phi[\lambda] $ from our numerical integration to be listed for each of the for-loop iterations rather than its interpolating function?

### Part 2

Ideally then I would like to use the command `Interpolation`  to interpolate these points and then use `ImageTransformation` to transform images from these interpolations.

I did this so far

```
numericalmap = {};
For[i = 1, i < 11, i++, \[Phi]csgen = (1 + 0.1 i)*Pi;
 M = 1; E0 = 1; \[Theta]cs = Pi/2;
 Nx = Sin[\[Theta]cs]*Cos[\[Phi]csgen];
 Ny = Sin[\[Theta]cs]*Sin[\[Phi]csgen];
 Nz = Cos[\[Theta]cs];
 nr = -Nx;
 n\[Phi] = -Ny;
 n\[Theta] = Nz;
 b = rc*Sin[\[Theta]c]*n\[Phi]/(1 - 2 M/rc)^1/2;
 B2 = rc^2/(1 - 2 M/rc)*(n\[Phi]^2 + n\[Theta]^2);
 prinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1))*nr;
 p\[Theta]initial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1/2))*rc*n\[Theta];
 {rc, \[Theta]c, \[Phi]c} = {200, Pi/2, 0};
 ham = {
   t'[\[Lambda]] + E0/(1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]]) == 0,
   r'[\[Lambda]] - (1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]]) pr[\[Lambda]] == 0,
   \[Theta]'[\[Lambda]] - P\[Theta][\[Lambda]]/r[\[Lambda]]^2 == 0,
   \[Phi]'[\[Lambda]] - b/(r[\[Lambda]]*Sin[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]])^2 ==
     0, pr'[\[Lambda]] + 
     M/r[\[Lambda]]^2 (E0^2/(1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]])^2 + 
        pr[\[Lambda]]^2) - B2/r[\[Lambda]]^3 == 0, 
   P\[Theta]'[\[Lambda]] - (b^2*
        Cos[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]])/(r[\[Lambda]]^2*
        Sin[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]]^3) == 0
   };
 haminital = {t[0] == 0, 
   r[0] == rc, \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]c, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]c, 
   pr[0] == prinitial, P\[Theta][0] == p\[Theta]initial};
 \[Phi]2 = 
  NDSolveValue[{ham, haminital}, {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, 
     P\[Theta]}, {\[Lambda], -100, 0}][[4]];
 numericalmap = Append[numericalmap, {\[Phi]csgen, \[Phi]2[-100]}]]

Interpolation[numericalmap]

Import["https://goo.gl/images/vYfAwT"]

ImageTransformation[
Import["https://goo.gl/images/vYfAwT"], 
Interpolation[numericalmap]
];
```

After this I also tried using ImageTransformation on this list as follows but am not entirely sure how to input our `Interpolation` function into it to transform the pixels by this function. Even if this does work surely it would transform every pixel by the same function resulting in a bland image.

If this can't be done not sure whether it's because I haven't used `ListInterpolation` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem actually starts one line above the one you marked. Try this:

```
numericalmap = {};
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
  ϕcsgen = (1 + 0.1 i)*Pi;
  M = 1; E0 = 1; θcs = Pi/2;
  Nx = Sin[θcs]*Cos[ϕcsgen];
  Ny = Sin[θcs]*Sin[ϕcsgen];
  Nz = Cos[θcs];
  nr = -Nx;
  nϕ = -Ny;
  nθ = Nz;
  b = rc*Sin[θc]*nϕ/(1 - 2 M/rc)^1/2;
  B2 = rc^2/(1 - 2 M/rc)*(nϕ^2 + nθ^2);
  prinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1))*nr;
  pθinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1/2))*rc*nθ;
  {rc, θc, ϕc} = {200, Pi/2, 0};
  ham =
   {t'[λ] + E0/(1 - (2 M)/r[λ]) == 0, 
    r'[λ] - (1 - (2 M)/r[λ]) pr[λ] == 0, 
    θ'[λ] - Pθ[λ]/r[λ]^2 == 0, 
    ϕ'[λ] - b/(r[λ]*Sin[θ[λ]])^2 == 0, 
    pr'[λ] + M/r[λ]^2 (E0^2/(1 - (2 M)/r[λ])^2 + pr[λ]^2) - B2/r[λ]^3 == 0, 
    Pθ'[λ] - (b^2*Cos[θ[λ]])/(r[λ]^2*Sin[θ[λ]]^3) == 0};
  haminital =
    {t[0] == 0, r[0] == rc, θ[0] == θc, ϕ[0] == ϕc,
     pr[0] == prinitial, Pθ[0] == pθinitial};
   ϕ2 = NDSolveValue[{ham, haminital}, {t, r, θ, ϕ, pr, Pθ}, {λ, -100, 0}][[4]];
   numericalmap = Append[numericalmap, {ϕcsgen, ϕ2[-100]}]]
```

Then evaluating `numericalmap` gives

> ```
> {{3.45575, -0.144726}, {3.76991, -0.231658}, {4.08407, -0.262885}, 
>  {4.39823, -0.258873}, {4.71239, -0.234244}, {5.02655, -0.197373}, 
>  {5.34071, -0.153051}, {5.65487, -0.104184}, {5.96903, -0.0526945}}
> ```

Notes

1. It is good practice to move the definition of `θcs` upwards so it will be evaluated before it is used.
2. Since the interpolating function for `ϕ` is the 4th item in the list returned by `NDSolveValue`, I use `[[4]]` to extract it.

Comment: Thank you so much , how could I then use this numerical map (a list of pairs of $(\phi cs, \phi [ -100 ] )$ ) and create an interpolation of it? I tried using `ListInterpolation` but it said too high order  Also, how can I create a chat about this question so not to fill the comments section?

Comment: @user61882. If you give `numericlmap` to [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html), it will return an interpolation function.

Comment: I added my attempts to the question body. In the paper on page 13 it specifically says  `ListInterpolation` was used. Also how do I then input that into ImageTransformation?

Comment: @user61882. Use `Interpolation` not `ListInterpolation`.

Comment: @user61882. You need 100 or more reputation points to open a chat room.

Comment: @Goldberg. Ok thanks, also  if I use the `Interpolation` command how can I apply that into the `ImageTransformation` command to transform the pixels of my image by this function? I have added to the main body

Comment: @user61882. Don't keep asking me to answer your updates in comments to this answer. Your question edits are sufficient to get the attention of anyone who cares to answer